# How to get Facebook Like to publish a thumbnail, description and link on newsfeed after "Like"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, thumbnails

I am adding a FB like button to my page, and currently when I "Like" the page, it only says it on my personal page with a small link to the facebook page associated to my website. I want it  to post a picture, description, and the link to my site. I am using the code generated from this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I debugged it and it says properties are missing even though I have them included in the code...

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.audiblecoffee.com%2Fbeta321432

Any reason on why this isn't working?

Comment: I see a thumbnail and description appearing exactly as the og meta tags specify.  I see this both when I like the site as well as when I specify the link in a status update.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.audiblecoffee.com">
```

This will make Facebook use `http://www.audiblecoffee.com` to look for OG tags, not the submitted URL. Change it to `http://www.audiblecoffee.com/beta321432/` (or leave it out) and things'll work fine.

Comment: That got rid of the errors. However, it still doesn't seem to post a thumbnail or description.

Comment: You don't seem to have made the recommended change - I still see the page setting `og:url` to the main, OG-less page of the site.